# PostgreSQL: error with parse JSON with ''

Tags: json, postgresql

can you get advise me how I can fix the error when I try to parse JSON from PostgreSQL table?

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Hint: Token "'" is invalid. Where: JSON data, line 1: [{'...
```

I have researched this issue and see that it comes up due to the fact that some contain '' in JSON:

```
[{'name':'cc','desc':'What is your credit card number? I promise to keep it real secure like.','type':'string','regex':'\\d+','min_length':1,'max_length':16,'example':'736363627'},{'name':'height','desc':'How tall are you?','type':'int','min':4,'max':666,'example':55},{'name':'likescake','desc':'Do you like cake?','type':'bool'},{'name':'address','desc':'What is your address','type':'string','min_length':5,'example':'blk 6 lot 26 blah blah'},{'name':'single','desc':'Are you single?','type':'bool'},{'name':'weight','desc':'what is your weight in kgs?','type':'float','example':55}]
```

another JSONs contain "":

```
[{"desc": "What is your credit card number? I promise to keep it real secure like.", "name": "cc", "type": "string", "regex": "\\d+", "max_length": 16, "min_length": 1}, {"max": "666", "min": "4", "desc": "How tall are you?", "name": "height", "type": "int"}, {"desc": "Do you like cake?", "name": "likescake", "type": "bool"}]
```

I try to parse with this command:

```
-- For multiple choice from JSON
SELECT
  s.projectid,
  s.prompttype,
  el.inputs->>'name' AS name,
  el.inputs->>'desc' AS desc,
  el.inputs->>'values' AS values,
  s.created,
  s.modified
FROM source_redshift.staticprompts AS s,
     jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs::jsonb) el(inputs);
```

Comment: You need to store valid JSON in your column. If you had defined the column with the type `jsonb` (as recommended) you would have gotten the error when _saving_ this invalid data. You will need to fix the data by converting the invalid JSON to valid JSON

Comment: Your json strings are invalid. You will need to correct them manually, e.g. using regex. Take this opportunity and change the column data type to jsonb, so that you do not have to worry about it in the future. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jim-Jones said, JSON is invalid.

There are many online and offline JSON validation tools. I recomend to use it.

Its help you detect the cause of problems: is it invalid JSON or error in your code.

For example, [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) said that it replaced incorrect quotes.